# Remove element by value a-la Knockout

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs, knockout.js

This is something of a two-part question that has to do with manipulating elements within an array of data in Angular.  It seems like pretty universally the way to remove an element from an array in the ViewModel is

```
$scope.array.splice(index, 1);
```

This seems a little shaky to me, and I prefer how Knockout handles this [with `.remove` and observable arrays](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/observableArrays.html): `vm.array.remove(item)`.

I have found that you can do this which is a bit better:

```
$scope.array.splice($scope.array.indexOf(item), 1);
```

but it's more verbose and `.indexOf` may not work as you expect depending upon what `item` is.

Is there any construct for Angular that will allow you to easily remove an item from an array by its value?

Also based on [this video from Egghead.io](https://egghead.io/lessons/angularjs-defining-a-method-on-the-scope), it makes sense to remove dependencies within ViewModel methods and not rely on scope.  Would it be preferred to pass in the array that you were removing the item from as well:

```
<input type=submit ng-click="remove(array, item)">
array.splice(array.indexOf(item), 1)
```

Or is there a reason to prefer using `$scope` (or the controller) within the remove method?

Comment: what's your pick on below answer. I would love to discuss!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately or Fortunately, Knockout does it the same way we are doing with Angular i.e. `splice` method

If you look at the source code of `observableArray.remove(item)` in knockout library -

```
 'remove': function (valueOrPredicate) {
        var underlyingArray = this.peek();
        var removedValues = [];
        var predicate = typeof valueOrPredicate == "function" && !ko.isObservable(valueOrPredicate) ? valueOrPredicate : function (value) { return value === valueOrPredicate; };
        for (var i = 0; i < underlyingArray.length; i++) {
            var value = underlyingArray[i];
            if (predicate(value)) {
                if (removedValues.length === 0) {
                    this.valueWillMutate();
                }
                removedValues.push(value);
                underlyingArray.splice(i, 1);
                i--;
            }
        }
        if (removedValues.length) {
            this.valueHasMutated();
        }
        return removedValues;
    }
```

It does the same thing, it parse through the array and compare the given value and performs `splice`.

They have written reusable module for the same to make it easy to use for developers. I believe you can do the same by writing custom directive in your Angular code. You can use above code for a reference. It's just that Angular does not have any reusable directive for that... yet.. may be we can ask for a pull request after making one :-)

But your question is very good and one should have such reusable module.

Comment: I was thinking something like `angular.collectionRemove(collection, item)` -- perhaps I'll propose it

Comment: Yeah, let me know once you request it. I'll add it. I'll try building one custom directive for the same, will update it here if I get any success.

Comment: https://github.com/ajcrites/angular.js/blob/master/src/Angular.js#L687 -- this is not a public method though :(